# mod_rewrite assets in a directory to another server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I direct all files in `/media/` to `http://anothersite.com/media` with `mod_rewrite`? I'm directing a staging site's image requests to it's main site's directory.

The following isn't working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^media/(.*) http://anothersite.com/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Haven't messed with Apache config much - forgive me if this is a lame-o question.

Comment: You can use: `RewriteRule ^(media/.*) http://anothersite.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: On a request for `/media/image1.jpg` for example, do you want to serve the content found at `http://anothersite.com/media/image1.jpg` or `http://anothersite.com/image1.jpg`? The first sentence in the question tells you want the first URL, the `RewriteRule` gets you the second one. Which one?

Comment: @axiac latter - now covered with GentlemanMax's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're redirecting to another site, I believe you need to invoke [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) instead of `mod_rewrite`.  you do that by changing your `[QSA, L]` to `[P]`.  So something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteRule ^media/(.*) http://anothersite.com/media/$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```

Otherwise, your rewrite rule looks good.

A possibly better alternative to this is would be a local PHP script that loads and returns the image that you redirect to.

In that scenario, your rewrite rule would look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteRule ^media/(.*) /imageFetcher.php?img=$1 [QSA, L]
</IfModule>
```

Then you would need to create a file `imageFetcher.php`.  with the following

```
<?php
    //Do some checks to make sure this request came from your site, you won't want external users accessing this script
    $img_file = $_GET['img'];
    $img_data = file_get_contents("http://anothersite.com/$img_file");

    //Possibly verify that $img_data is a valid image file using imgjpeg(), imgpng(), etc

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); //This assumes your image is a jpeg.  If the image could be a png/gif/etc you'll need to do some logic to set the proper header.
    echo $img_data;
    exit();
```

Comment: Hrm, this isn't working for me either. Can I log these requests out to a file to review? Bugfixing this server stuff is beyond me

Comment: I usually use a tester like [this](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).  Have you considered just using a local php script to get the file off the remote server?

Comment: I edited my solution to include a php fetcher as a possible solution.

Comment: Thank you, worth considering. I ran your answer through that tester and found one issue - the `RewriteRule` doesn't maintain the directory so it needs to be explicit like `^media/(.*) http://anothersite.com/media/$1 [P]`. Update and I'll accept your answer